# Android Facebook Change/Set new AccessToken

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to allow a user to login as a page with facebook - so if there's an easier way of doing it over what I'm trying, please feel free to tell me -

Currently, I log the user in with LoginManager and get the details of the user (i.e. their page and page access_token) using a GraphRequest.  I then put the user's pages into a spinner so the user can select which page to post as (including their own).

Here's the problem.  I have the `access_token` as a string from when the user logs in and I pull the information and I see the `access_token` when the user selects the page they want, but I'm totally unsure on how to set a new access token, especially from a string.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
GraphRequest requestPage = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
    currentAccessToken,
    "/me/accounts",
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = response.getJSONObject().getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject page = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String pageName = page.getString("name");
                    String pageToken = page.getString("access_token");
                    if(!pageName.equals("")) {
                        //I know there's a better way of getting the name and token together in an array, but I don't know how
                        pages_array.add(pageName);
                        pages_token_array.add(pageToken);
                        facebook_pages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        pages_array.clear();
                        pages_token_array.clear();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StartPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, pages_array);
            spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
            spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            page_spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        }
    });
    Bundle pageParameters = new Bundle();
    pageParameters.putString("fields", "name,access_token,picture{url}");
    requestPage.setParameters(pageParameters);
    requestPage.executeAsync();
);
```

Then here's how I select the spinner

```
facebook_select_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String spinner_value = page_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int spinner_position = page_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        String newAccessToken = pages_token_array.get(spinner_position);
        //AccessToken token = new AccessToken(newAccessToken);
        //TODO: SET NEW ACCESS TOKEN
    };
});
```

Like I said, I have the selection working and I can see the access token if I were to log it or Toast it on the button press.  I just don't know how to CHANGE The access token.

Any ideas?

Comment: why cant you just append the access token to your request params  ? like in their graph explorer ? or rest API calls  ?

Comment: @lamdadj22, Can you? I haven't been able to put an access token in the graph explorer.  I found a work around, but it's brittle and I need to fix a few things.